# sudo mount from webserver (Apache) by mod_php, result not visible by root

Tags: arch-linux, mount, sudo

Intial question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598201/umounting-through-exec-with-sudo-the-user-is-a-sudoer-with-nopasswd

Basically, I have a PHP script, that:

```
exec('sudo mount /dev/md/stone:supershare /mnt/supershare');
```

It completes with no error, exit code 0.

From a separate `root` session, I `cat /proc/mounts` and it shows no signs of my `supsershare`.

Attempt with `root` to `rm -r /mnt/supershare`:

```
[root@stone mnt]# rm -r supershare/
rm: cannot remove ‘supershare/’: Device or resource busy
```

Attempt with `root` to `umount /mnt/supershare`:

```
[root@stone mnt]# umount /mnt/supershare
umount: /mnt/supershare: not mounted
```

Attempt with `root` to `mdadm --stop /dev/md/stone:supershare`:

```
[root@stone mnt]# mdadm --stop /dev/md/stone\:supershare
mdadm: Cannot get exclusive access to /dev/md/stone:supershare:Perhaps a running process, mounted filesystem or active volume group?
```

Any attempts to perform the same commands with sudo from webserver are successful (they show signs of mountpoint, they unmount the devices, stop the raids etc.).

And, yes, I am root:

```
[root@stone mnt]# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel),19(log)
```

How come `root` does not get notified about the mounts performed by webserver?
In what scenarios does `mount` become local to effective user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the [hassle has been resolved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98191/23212).

It was the Apache's corresponding `systemd` service, that had [`PrivateTmp=true`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateTmp=) directive. Apparently, the directive executes the process with a new file system namespace.

You can learn more about adventures to resolving the issue, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19682810/393406).